# How to force NavController#onGraphCreated to be called when calling setGraph twice with androidx.navigation 2.7.5

Tags: android, androidx, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I'm using `androidx.navigation:navigation-*:2.7.5` and noticed a potential issue with `NavController#onGraphCreated` not being called when calling `setGraph` twice. This seems to be related to the commit found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/d22366d59a46aa16aa79d1d691cd5cb55f56c378

I'm trying to find a way to force `NavController#onGraphCreated` to be called in this scenario.

Here's why I need this:
I have an Activity with launchMode set to `singleTop`.
When the Activity is started for the first time, onCreate is called and `NavController#setGraph` is used to set the initial graph.
When the Activity is started again (via startActivity), `onNewIntent` is called. Inside `onNewIntent`, I call `NavController#setGraph` again to update the UI.
This worked fine in `2.7.4`, but in `2.7.5`, the UI no longer updates when calling `setGraph` in `onNewIntent`.

Is there any way to force `NavController#onGraphCreated` to be called in this situation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.